# Why can't we say that moon attracts the earth?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

We know that the Gravitational force at which earth attracts moon is also equal to the force in which moon attracts earth as the distance and the G and the masses are same then why can't we say that moon attracts the earth ?

Comment: It is the antropic principle taken over from everyday life : A man is swinging a child in a circle and not the child the man, even though the forces at the hands are equal.

Comment: Why are you yelling?

Comment: There is no such thing as a gravitational force. Gravity is an acceleration. If you look at the gravitational acceleration formula, it is independent of the mass of the body that is being accelerated, which means that the accelerations of Earth and Moon are different.

Comment: What do you think so? Of course you can say that the Moon attracts the Earth!

Answer (score 5):

The truth is that both the moon and the earth attract each other with the same force but the acceleration of both are different due to the difference in their masses. That is why perceive the moon revolving around the earth whereas in reality both the earth and the moon revolve around a common point known as the barycenter which lies under the surface of the earth. So, the earth also wobbles a bit when the moon revolves around the earth. To conclude, whether we say the earth attracts the moon or the moon attracts the earth, we are essentially referring to the same thing. There is also the anthropic principle due to which we as humans want our place in the universe to be special and not general. This is also one of the reasons why people considered the earth to be the center of the universe in earlier times.